# logging any changes users make in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, logging, request

Im working on an in-house developed app, written in PHP.

We have several employee users that can make dozens of different changes, such as: add new employee accounts, courses, students, questions, tests etc. as well as modify or delete those.

My goal is to write a function(s) to log in a MySQL table any change that someone makes.

I can get this done one by one for each request.

So for example, a request can be sent by an user to add a new employee account to the database.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['newemployee'])){
    $db = new db();
    $insertrow = $db ->insertRow("INSERT INTO employees (firstname, lastname, email, role, color) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", array($_REQUEST['firstname'],$_REQUEST['lastname'],$_REQUEST['email'],$_REQUEST['role'],$_REQUEST['colorpicker1']));
}
```

what I can do is write an if statement for any individual request.
E.g.

// I already have a table named `logs`, its very dirty here but you get the idea, it does the job.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['newemployee'])){
        $done_by = $_SESSION['loguser']['id']; // this is how we track the user ids.
        $action = 'created new employee account, email: '.$_REQUEST['email'];
        $db = new db();
        $insertrow = $db ->insertRow("INSERT INTO logs(user_id, action) VALUES (?, ?)", array($done_by, $action));
```

I would like to, if possible, generalize/automate this process as much as possible to avoid writing dozens and dozens of if statements for each `REQUEST` that can be triggered.
My idea was something like this:

```
if (ANY REQUEST is triggered){
    # tell me what it is (e.g. 'newemployee')
    # here I will insert the log in to the DB. The `action` field will not be very specific in this case, but I can live with that.
}
```

I can't seem to just generally `if REQUEST` though, is it even possible?

Comment: I don't have the complete idea of your code but I believe if db() is a class you will be getting $_REQUEST and $_SESSION values in it so if I am correct and note this is a complete hunch you can try adding its constructor and write you log code there that will be run every time you are initializing db

Comment: If this is a copy of the real code, then it is not protected for sql injection. Unless all the logic of protection is behind the `insertRow` method.

Other than that, you could write sql-triggers on your tables. You don't have to rewrite the software since finding out all the locations where things are being inserted seems a lot of work.

Comment: @Leroy thanks for the input, the logic is behind `insertRow`

Comment: @Leroy - _"If this is a copy of the real code, then it is not protected for sql injection"_ - How's that? What is it you're referring to? I don't see any indications of that in the posted code.

Comment: @M.Eriksson passing `$_REQUEST[]` data straight into the `INSERT` statement without escaping it using the proper mysql escape functions. Hence my next statement. If that is covered in the `insertRow` method, than it's fine.

Comment: @Leroy - If they actually did that, then yes. But if you look at their code, they are passing in a statement with placeholders as the first argument and the values in an array as the second argument. Nowhere in the posted code are they inserting any data into the query directly. I would argue that since we don't know how `insertRow()` works, we can't say anything about the security of their queries. As a side note: _"without escaping it using the proper mysql escape functions"_ - there are no "proper" escape functions. You should use prepared statements with placeholders over escaping.

Comment: I totally forgot prepared statements are escaped by default. My bad!

Comment: @Leroy - Sorry for being picky, but prepared statements aren't escaped at all. :-) The SQL statement and the values are being sent to the server separately, so they never get "inserted" into the query, so there's no need for escaping.